# Model photo choice for better conversion rate : is same sex more appealing than opposite sex?

Tags: psychology, marketing, landing-page, user-perception, cognition

I am creating a landing page targeted to men of age 18 to 45 years.
It's supposed to promote a nationwide recruitment effort of temporary workers needed in production plants.

The photo of a smiling factory worker will be used on the top of the page next to the main slogan.

What is better regarding conversion rate : a male worker or a female worker?

Same question asked differently : **should I use the "identification to self" approach or the "sexual attraction" approach**?

Comment: To my knowledge a female front figure/voice generally creates a calm and trust in the beholder (which in the scenario can be either a man or woman). So in the scenario you describe, where a visitor will in the blink of an eye determine whether they want to "go into business" with this recruiter or not I would from the top of my head argue that a female front figure would generally produce the higher conversion rate.

Comment: Perhaps you could argue that including such a photograph is only a distraction. You might well expect no photograph to outperform both male/female variants.

Comment: @Brendon well, if you take a look at most of the slides from http://www.slideshare.net/ioninteractive/50-landing-page-best-practices-13034333 , you'll notice that a model is almost always present on a landing page. And it's a woman most of the times.

Comment: I'd have expected there to have been some relevent academic research on this topic - otherwise it would be an easy thing to A/B test.

Comment: @PhillipW Unfortunately, I can't A/B test for this project. That's why some proved facts/researches would be highly welcome.

Comment: @AndroidHustle Thanks a lot for the comment. My gut feeling says exactly the same but it would help If I could have something to back up my claims when I have to explain my artistic choices to my manager.

Comment: I can't find the article, but I know I've read where you want a female image, because a male image can appear threatening to women and a source of competition to men. That said, I strongly suggest @rk's answer. Images that are clearly of models can be a turn-off and a reason to question the legitimacy of the web site.

Comment: Sex sells = much more of a marketing topic than UX

Comment: But, to answer it in a UX manner = this is what A/B testing is for.

Answer (score 15):

I would rather go with **actual workers than models**. If you are asking this question on UX Q&A site, I would give you the **UCD approach rather than the cogsci approach to marketing**.

- By using actual workers in actual working conditions, you run the advantage of being **transparent and conveying much more information through the image** than what you could have done using models.
- If the **'teams' in the factory are composed of men and women**, then show that. Else what is the point of showing a picture of female workers when they are working in isolation? Are you saying 'We have men and women workers. They do not work together, but, you can catch a sneak peak during lunch hours. Come work for us!'

---

[**Twitter** made this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vccZkELgEsU) (not quite seriously) but it still went viral and did the job (arguably) better than a serious commercial would have.

Comment: +1 I agree. Using real life pics rather than stock photos is always better in my opinion. More trustworthy and not as stale as a stock photo easily get.

Comment: How long until someone counters with "but real people are ugly!"?